# Unexpected behaviour. Huge size increase when adding new SubContract()

Tags: solidity, contract-design, solc, compilation, constructor

I have a contract similar to:

```
contract Contract01 {
  SubContract _refContract;
  ...
   constructor() public {
      refContract = new SubContract();
   }

   function setSubContractRef(SubContract refContract) {
      _refContract = refContract;
   }
}
```

When I add the new SubContract() the bytecode increase is "huge" since it looks like the byte code of the SubContract is also increased. This causes the max-contract size to be reached with easy.

I found it's possible to create a SubContract in a different TX and pass the reference to Contract01 in setSubContractRef, but I'm wondering whether there is a simpler way involving fewer steps.

Comment: What's `refContract;)`? An eye-blinking input argument?

Comment: @goodvibration Just a type error. Fixed!

Comment: Deploy `SubContract` separately, and pass its address to `Contract01`. In fact, you are already doing it (more or less), so just copy the contents of function `setSubContractRef` into the constructor, and you're done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Answering myself two year later for those arriving here through Google Airlines):

**"new" keyword is the culprit** in this case.

Each time "new" is used, the full code of the referenced smart-contract will be included in order to allow to build new SubContract instances **at runtime**.

If just pre-built references are passed, the compiler is smart-enough to just generate the minimum code to call public methods of the referenced contract.